# How can I change the structure of all documents in a CouchDB database?

Tags: java, couchdb, ektorp

I have to change the structure of all existing documents in one of my CouchDB databases that contain a certain field.
Right now, the field is just a simple String, for example:

```
{
  // some other fields
  "parameters": {
     "typeId": "something",
     "otherField": "dont_care"
  }
}
```

In this example, the field I'm interested is "typeId".
I want to make it an array of Strings because the requirements for this was modified :(
But I obviously need to keep the current value of the field in all documents! So, from the example above, the result would be:

```
{
  // some other fields
  "parameters": {
     "typeId": [ "something" ] // now we can have more items here
     "otherField": "dont_care"
  }
}
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved??

Just in case this helps: my Java web-application communicates with CouchDB through the Ektorp library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say first write a function (or method, or class) that converts old-style documents into new-style documents and also correctly handles irrelevant documents (such as a design document) if necessary. Write some unit tests until you are confident about this code.

The next step is basically a loop of finding old-style documents and updating them to become new-style documents, using your modification routine.

If you have a small data set, you can simply query `/_all_docs?include_docs=true` and work on your entire data set in one batch. If you have a larger data set, perhaps write a view which will identify old-style documents

```
function(doc) {
  // map function for "to_do" view
  if(doc.parameters && typeof doc.parameters == "string")
    emit(doc._id, doc)
}
```

This view will show you all old-style documents *to do*. To grab 50 more documents to convert, GET `/my_db/_design/converter/_view/to_do?limit=50`. Each row's `"value"` field will be a complete copy of the document, so you can run it through your converter function immediately.

Once you convert a document, you can either POST it back to the database, or build up a batch and use `_bulk_docs` to do the same. (Bulk docs is the same thing, just a little faster.) As each document is stored, it will disappear from the `to_do` view. (If you get a `409 Conflict` error, just ignore it.) Re-run this procedure until there are 0 rows in `to_do` and you're done!

You can judge from your situation how careful you need to be. If this is production data, you had better write good unit tests! If it is a development environment, just go for it!

A final trick is to create a new, empty database and replicate your main database to it. Now you have a duplicate sandbox to try your ideas. You can delete and re-replicate your sandbox until you are happy with your results.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What is the easiest way to write a converter function? I was thinking of only using the CouchDB HTTP API to do that and maybe run a JavaScript function as the converter function. Do you think it's possible or I'd be better off writing it in Java, using the Ektorp library that I'm already familiar with?

Comment: You can use this couchapp: http://harthur.github.com/costco/ Its pretty handy to have in your db.